# Unity não atualiza frames ao girar o personagem com o movimento do mouse

Tags: c#, unity3d

O meu Unity não esta dando erro, nem nada. Está tudo OK, mas o personagem não se mexe.
Já olhei o código e nada de erro , eu mexo o mouse e não acontece nada com o personagem. A versão do Unity é 4.6 e o código é esse:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float speed = 6f;
   Vector3 movement;
   Animator anim;
   Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
   int floorMask;
   float camRayLenght = 100f;

   void Awake(){
      floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");
      anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
      playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
   }

   void FixUpdate(){
      float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
      float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
      Move (h, v);
      Turning ();
      Animating (h, v);
   }

   void Move(float h,float v){
      //tertemina o movimento
      movement.Set(h,0f,v);
      //normaliza o movimento
      movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
      // efetua o movimento
      playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
   }

   //girar o jogador
   void Turning(){
      Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
      RaycastHit floorHit;

      if (Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLenght, floorMask)) {

          Vector3 playerToMouse=floorHit.point-transform.position;
          playerToMouse.y=0f;
          // rotaçao do personagem
          Quaternion newRotation= Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
          playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
      }
   }

   void Animating(float h,float v){
      bool walking = h != 0f || v!=0f;
      anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", walking);
   }
}
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49919/como-girar-o-personagem-conforme-o-movimento-do-mouse

Comment: Não está duplicada, o problema desta é diferente daquela que mandou o link. Basta ver o código, o "Floor" está correto nesta daí.

Comment: @Nils Bom, eu não marquei como duplicata, apenas postei um *link* de uma pergunta que possui título semelhante.

Comment: @renan Eu só queria avisar o moderador, não sabia do botão sinalizar. Um monte de gente viu esse link e o como o nome da pergunta era o mesmo eles sinalizaram como duplicata.

Answer (score 4):

O erro está em:

```
void FixUpdate(){
  float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
  float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
  Move (h, v);
  Turning ();
  Animating (h, v);
}
```

O Unity usa uma função interna chamada [FixedUpdate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

Tudo que estiver dentro dela será chamado a cada atualização de frame.
Se você usar outro nome, ele vai pensar que é outra função ou método.

Basta trocar o

```
FixUpdate()
```

por

```
 FixedUpdate ()
```

O código ficará assim:

```
void FixedUpdate(){
  float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
  float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
  Move (h, v);
  Turning ();
  Animating (h, v);
}
```

*Não se esqueça de dizer mais detalhes do tutorial que está fazendo para facilitar o pessoal que for tentar tirar tuas dúvidas
[Unity training day 2014: Survival Shooter](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21028)